# Making API calls from a unit test in React?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I am writing unit tests for my components using enzyme, mocha, chai, and sinon. In my components I import a library that constructs an API call with jQuery and use it in my component like so:

CategoryTree

```
_getCategoriesFromServer() {
        const _this = this;
        sdk.getJSON(_this.props.sdkPath, {
            itemsperpage: 10000
        }).done(function(data) {
            _this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                categories: _this.state.categories.concat(data)
            });
        }).fail(error => {
            console.log('ERROR', error);
        });
    }
```

Im calling this method in `componentDidMount`. The issue im having is with the testing. I am using Istanbul for test coverage, and I noticed that no matter what I do, the AJAX call is unsuccessful. Here is one of the tests:

```
it('should call componentDidMount', () => {
            sinon.spy(CategoryTree.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
            wrapper = mount(<CategoryTree {...props} />);
            expect(CategoryTree.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).to.be.true;
            console.log(wrapper.props());
            console.log(wrapper.state());
            console.log(wrapper.debug());
        });
```

When this test runs it returns this error in the terminal:

```
ERROR { readyState: 0,
  getResponseHeader: [Function: getResponseHeader],
  getAllResponseHeaders: [Function: getAllResponseHeaders],
  setRequestHeader: [Function: setRequestHeader],
  overrideMimeType: [Function: overrideMimeType],
  statusCode: [Function: statusCode],
  abort: [Function: abort],
  state: [Function: state],
  always: [Function: always],
  then: [Function: then],
  promise: [Function: promise],
  pipe: [Function: then],
  done: [Function: add],
  fail: [Function: add],
  progress: [Function: add],
  complete: [Function: add],
  success: [Function: add],
  error: [Function: add],
  responseJSON: undefined,
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'error' }
```

The call works as expected in the application, just not in the test. Is there a reason for this?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the _getCategoriesFromServer method is in the CategoryTree component.

Comment: You probably want to mock those API calls. Doesn't really make any sense to test that an API call worked.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I agree completely, unfortunately my work wants 100% test coverage. :(

Comment: Unit tests shouldn't touch the wire, those would be integration tests. @SergiuParaschiv is correct to state the API call should be mocked.

Comment: @lux Okay, thank you for the explanation everyone. Can I mock the API call using sinon?

Comment: You bet! Check this out: http://elijahmanor.com/unit-test-like-a-secret-agent-with-sinon-js/

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much guys! @lux